# How can I apply a fullscreen shader on a specific layer?

Tags: unity, shaders, camera, particles, unity-shader-graph

How do I apply a full screen shader on one layer of objects using LWRP/URP and shader graph? I want to pixelate only my particlesystems, but nothing else. I want the effect of pixelcamera, but only on particlesystems.

Normaly I whould have a seperate camera rendering the particlesystem and then pixelate only that camera, but I can't have a transparent background (dont clear) for some reason while using LWRP. If I have 2 cameras, the background only turns black and only renders the particles :(

Comment: You cannot. A full-screen shader, by definition, applies to the whole screen, not to a specific layer selectively.  Can you show us an example the effect you want to create? There might be other routes by which we can achieve the same outcome.

Comment: Here you can see a pixel effect on everything exept for a round sprite: https://imgur.com/VcxLXyh using 2 cameras. I want to replicate the same for a LWRP/URP game

Comment: This looks like an effect you could achieve simply by using a pixelated texture for every asset except the circle sprite. Do you have a more complex use case that would demand we do something more exotic?

Comment: To be more specific, I want to make some particlesystems pass a pixel filter as seen here: https://youtu.be/fMEWdR0pU0k but in a LWRP project while still keeping everything else in full HD. (In the video I used two cameras and set the clear flag to dont clear for one camera, but I can't replicate this in a LWRP project. I want to achive the left particlesystem without pixelating the character and also keeping the propertys (materials/glow) of the particlesystem)